# Route for two optional parameter for a specific controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In a specific controller, I have actions that accept two parameters. Some of the actions are `get` and some of them work over `post`.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CodeRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string group, string system)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CodeCreate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ZCodes code, string group, string system)
```

Query strings are something like:

```
http://localhost:3086/xxx/CodeRead/01/00
```

I've defined the following routes, but I always get an empty `group`. `system` and `request` are fine.

```
    routes.MapRoute("Parameters", "xxx/{action}/{group}/{system}",
        new { controller = "xxx", action = "CodeRead", group = UrlParameter.Optional, system = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I've exchanged the routes places too, but it didn't work!

Comment: Your "Parameters" route needs to be before the "Default" route. Can you clarify what you mean by _"I always get an empty group, system and request are fine."_ - which ones are empty and which ones are fine.

Comment: Just group is empty. I've tried exchanging route's places, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your "Parameters" route must be first. But the `ActionResult` method you have shown is a POST, What is the signature of the GET method your referring to when you use `../xxx/CodeRead/01/00`

Comment: I've put that route in the first, and it didn't change a thing. That `ActionResult` is actually a `get` one, but I'll add a `post` one too. I have some other [binding problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472565/model-binding-fails-with-kendo-grid) too, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Why do you have parameter `DataSourceRequest request` in the GET method? You have 3 parameters, but `../xxx/CodeRead/01/00` is only passing 2

Comment: I think Kendo Grid needs that for its `Read` action. So how should I define the route?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kendo grid so can't be sure, but if you only pass 2 parameters to a method expecting 3, then one must be null

Comment: I have similar actions that expect an `Id` among the `request`, and they work fine with the default route. I can see the `request` data in the `Form Data` section of `Params` tab in F12 and it has the right values in the server side, so it shouldn't be the problem. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541959/3967440). Route is fine, the model contains a field with the name of `group`, I just need to rename that parameter to something else.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CodeRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string somethingElse, string system)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CodeCreate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ZCodes model, string somethingElse, string system)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Parameters on top of default

```
routes.MapRoute("Parameters", "xxx/{action}/{group}/{system}",
        new { controller = "xxx", action = "CodeRead", group = UrlParameter.Optional, system = UrlParameter.Optional });
}   

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```